# Getting error when trying to install Golang plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: go

After installing the community version of IntelliJ IDEA for windows I go to settings -> plugins -> browse repositories -> manage repositories -> add url

and then I add the url of

https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin

click ok, but get the error message below.

[image]

I tried to look around everywhere but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: wait, I'm little confused here, Did you add this URL `https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/alpha/5047` or `https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin`?

Comment: Yes I added the wrong url, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the plugin is now released in the official plugin repository for plugins so unless you really want to get the bleeding edge versions, I'd recommend you to use those versions.